# Array is different dimension than it's supposed to be

Tags: r, arrays

I have a problem with my code in R. For this input (and AFAIK only this input), the dimension of my array `matrixForSums` is different that it's supposed to be. It's supposed to be 113, but instead, the dimensions are 112. If I print `sizeForBeta`, it's 113 but if I print `dim(matrixForSums)`, it's 112.

Funny thing is, if I choose any other input, it's exactly the dimension it's supposed to be. If `sizeForBeta` is 130, then `dim(matrixForSums)` is 130.

Can you help me identify the problem?

```
    rowNumber<-1
    startIntervalForBeta<- -0.051
    stopIntervalForBeta<-0.062
    movementSizeForBeta<-0.001
    sizeForBeta<-0
    differenceForBeta <- startIntervalForBeta
    sizeForBeta<-(stopIntervalForBeta-startIntervalForBeta)/movementSizeForBeta
    beta0<-array(dim=c(sizeForBeta))
    my_range <- 0:(sizeForBeta)
    for(i in my_range) { 
      beta0[i]<- differenceForBeta
      differenceForBeta<- differenceForBeta+movementSizeForBeta
    }
    matrixForSums= array(0, dim=c(sizeForBeta))
```

Comment: This is really interesting. I never noticed this. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) is very useful which should also answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you think that it's 113, but it could be that it's 112,99999999999999 .. and R show you 113.
So just check it :

> floor(sizeForBeta)

[1] 112